# How to include extjs component in gxt and gwt?

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt

My application is built using gxt 4.0.0. Few features are not available in sencha gxt 4.0.0. So we have planned to use extjs components. Can you please tell me how to include extjs components in sencha gxt?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to JSNI or better JsInterop to wrap ExtJs and use it in GWT.

Also, you can take a look here:

http://eemi2010.github.io/ext4j/

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to implement your example and it worked fine. Can you please tell me the location of Pivot grid in your jar file. Because we are facing trouble with Pivot Grid. Thanks.

Comment: That's not my framework. But, maybe you can try to get in contact with eemi2010.

Comment: The api wrapper above will work good. Just a note, Sencha is working on a generated ExtJs Java api using a JsInterop generator, which should be out in the middle of 2017.